# Shape Detection (circle, square, rectangle, triangle, ellipse) for a camera captured image + i OS 5 + Open CV

Tags: ios5, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and need to know the method of OpenCV which detects different shapes (circle, square, rectangle, triangle, ellipse) in a camera captured image for iPhone.

so, could someone directs me to the right direction (references/articles/anything) that which techniques are better to get it done.

Thanks..

iOmi

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will probably need to look at an edge detector such as [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=canny) to extract the shapes into a binary image. (Although this may be expensive for the iphone)

For circles I would have a look at the [HoughCircles](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=hough#houghcircles).

For squares and rectangles you should look at the [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) method and the sample code `squares.cpp` in the samples directory when you downloaded opencv.

With a quick google search I was able to find an article about [detecting shapes in C#](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_%28Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line%29_Detection_in_CSharp) which roughly corresponds to the methods you would use in another language while using the opencv library.

I have not used opencv in ios but I hope this will help get you started.